# Stuck with "Connecting to SSH server" message on SSH connecting to GCP VM

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I wanted to start a wordpress site linked to a GCP machine I have with a domain I bought from Google Domains. However, when I try to connect to my wordpress site's admin page from the VM Instances page.

[image]

with <kbd>LOG INTO THE ADMIN PANEL</kbd> , I get:

```
 Access Interdit
 You are not authorized to access https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/
```

*Access prohibited, You are not authorized to access*

And when I try to do it from the url :

```
 Access Interdit
 You are not authorized to access https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/?redirect_to=https://thedataclan.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1
```

I think it's because SSL is no longer set, but when I try to connect to the virtual machine with <kbd>SSH</kbd> I can't get past this message:

```
 Connection to SSH server...
```

So how do I connect to a virtual machine's SSH server on GCP so I can add the SSL certificate?

## Update 9/06/2023

I tried to connect myself con the VM Web GUI, with the <kbd>SSH</kbd> button but, now, I have:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console web GUI and access the VM from there. Double-check firewall rules for ports 22, 80 and 443. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnHanley ! Unfortunately I can't access the VM from the web GUI. I've added the screenshot. And I don't know where to check for firewall rules

Comment: Did you follow the troubleshooting document? Please post text in English and not screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Please check and confirm the VPC network where the VM instance is part of by going into

Navigation Panel > Compute Engine > VM instances

Click the name of the VM instance then scroll down to `Network interfaces`.

From there, click the `Network` name and it will take you to VPC network detals.  Go to the `Firewalls` tab and make sure that you have an `Ingress` firewall rule for `Port 80`.

Additionally, as @JohnHanley suggested, please try to follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors) as it describes common errors that you may run into when connecting to virtual machine (VM) instances using SSH, ways to resolve errors, and methods for diagnosing failed SSH connections.

Answer (score 0):

In configuring OSLogin on GCP, following the `SSH` setup method outlined in the official documentation did not work as expected. After two days of research, I eventually switched to using an Identity Provider (IDP) through GCP IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy) forwarding to make it work properly. I have summarized the steps for your reference, and permissions were primarily set using built-in roles, which were sufficient for my use case.

**Step 1**

Need to set up Firewall Roles

```
[Allow TCP 22,3386 ingress to 35.235.240.0/20]
```

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tfOq.png

**Step 2**

Need Role permissions.

- `Compute Admin`（Mandatory, recommended to be placed at the machine level）
- `Compute OS Admin Login`（Mandatory, recommended to be placed at the machine level）
- `Compute Instance Admin (v1)`（Mandatory, must be placed at the project level）
- `IAP-secured Tunnel User`（Mandatory, recommended to be placed at the project level.）
- `Service Account User`（Mandatory, must be placed at the project level.）
- `Monitoring Viewer`（Check SSH connection error troubleshooting, not necessary.）
- `Network Management Admin`（Check SSH connection error troubleshooting, not necessary.）
- `Organization Policy Viewer`（Check SSH connection error troubleshooting, not necessary.）

**Step 3**

Need to configure metadata(Can be configured at the project or machine level, recommended to be placed at the project level.)

- `enable-oslogin` TRUE
- `serial-port-enable` TRUE

Hope to provide assistance to people with similar issues.

Refer:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console
- https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam